# Simplify conditional expression

Tags: scheme, conditional-statements

Is it possible to rewrite the expression below so that `(foo)` only appears once?  As it stands it's not terrible, but these repeated calls to `(foo)` make the code hard to read.

```
(cond
 (a
  (x)
  (foo))
 (b
  (y)
  (foo))
 (else
  (z)
  (bar)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is technically "answering your question," but I would disagree that the repeated calls to `foo` make the code "hard to read". Indeed, I would claim that they make it *easier* to read. Specifically, in the refactored versions, you have conditional branches with trailing code (the call to foo). This means that as a reader, I have to keep in mind while I'm reading the conditional the fact that there's more that happens later. Even more importantly, looking at the `foo` in the refactored code, we can't say for sure what code executed before this one; the original one didn't have this problem.

When large blocks of code are repeated, it makes code hard to read and fragile. When a single call is repeated, as here, it generally makes the code easier to read, especially if the function has a meaningful name.

Here, let me reindent that for you:

```
(cond
  [a (x)
     (foo)]
  [b (y)
     (foo)]
  [else (z)
        (bar)])
```

Answer (score 2):

If by `(foo)` you mean something complicated, I suggest:

```
(let ()
  (define (f) (foo))
  (cond
    (a     (x) (f))
    (b     (y) (f))
    (else  (z) (f))))
```

or

```
(let ((f (lambda () (foo))))
  (cond
    (a     (x) (f))
    (b     (y) (f))
    (else  (z) (f))))
```

Comment: Shouldn't that simply be `(let ((f foo)) ...`?

Comment: That depends on the situation.  If a and b have side effects that affect foo, then you will get different results.

Comment: I see. I tend to forget about side effects, since I never use them myself.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily more readable :) but this will work.

```
(cond ((or a b) ((cond (a (x)) (b (y))) (foo)) (else (z) (bar)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
(cond 
  ((cond
     (a
      (x)
      #t)
     (b
      (y)
      #t)
     (else
      (z)
      #f)) (foo))
  (else (bar)))
```

This does not introduce additional testing, in case `a` or `b` are complex expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option:

```
(let ((myfoo (lambda (x) (x) (foo))))
  (cond (a (myfoo x))
        (b (myfoo y))
        (else (z) (bar))))
```